# Protractor: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated

Tags: javascript, protractor

I was trying to locate an element to set the value under a form (popped up after clicked on a button on a page), but unable to locate such element after the form popped up, with below error:

```
Failed: invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated
```

The HTML code snippets are as follows:

```
<input class="form-control fc_short not-empty ng-pristine ng-not-empty ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched" ng-model="myNGModel" name="NGModel" ng-required="true" required="required" style="" type="text">
```

Below were the implemented codes:

```
it('should enter ABC value', function() {
    var elem = element.all(by.model('myNGModel')).first();
    var theStr = "ABC";
    browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elem.getWebElement()).then(function() {
        elem.clear();
        elem.sendKeys(theStr);
        expect(elem.getAttribute('value')).toEqual(theStr);
    });
});
```

Am I miss out any important area? I was able to locate this element using XPath like below:

```
var elem = element(by.xpath('//*[@id="MyFormID"]/div/div/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/input'));
```

Below highlighted its CSS path:

```
html.ng-scope body.modal-open div.pushmenu.cbp-spmenu-push ui-view.ng-scope section#MainArea ng-include.ng-scope div#MyFormID.modal.modal-create.modal-2-col.ng-scope.in div.modal-dialog div.modal-content form.ng-pristine.ng-valid-required.ng-invalid.ng-invalid-required div.modal-body div.row div.col-md-8.col-md-pull-4 div.spanel div.top_panel div.form-group input.form-control.fc_short.not-empty.ng-pristine.ng-not-empty.ng-valid.ng-valid-required.ng-touched
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception gets thrown on the `clear` method block

```
    elem.clear();
    elem.sendKeys(theStr);
    expect(elem.getAttribute('value')).toEqual(theStr);
```

Although the element is present on the page, it cannot be interacted with—the input would be `read only` that's why it is throwing this error. You may need to wait for some time in order for the element to be intractable or do it explicitly.

Please read this explanation given [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/InvalidElementStateException.html).

Comment: I have removed elem.clear() and now I am facing this error - Failed: element not visible

Comment: I tried also waited explicitly after removed elem.clear() but it just given timed out.
**Failed: Expected 'by.model("myNGModel")' to be present and visible. After 308 driverWaitIterations. Last webdriver error: TimeoutError: Wait timed out after 10006ms**

Comment: The issue is not with `clear` method - as a general your element cannot be interacted with. Try to see if you can do it manually and then see the changes in DOM. Otherwise, you can provide a minimal example or the URL.

Comment: This form is dependent on another modal-content class on same page.

Comment: For example, I will navigated into the page, click on a link to open a form to insert details, then save it and follow by open this MyFormID form to fill in data. The earlier form I was able to detect those elements, but not for the MyFormID form's elements.

Comment: It's difficult to know or predict why the element is not displayed with this information. One of the other approaches is to use JS to force the visibility to be true

Comment: Below is the selector information:

`#MyFormID > div > div > form > div.modal-body > div > div.col-md-8.col-md-pull-4 > div > div.top_panel > div:nth-child(3) > input`